# Fast execution plan and search, slow to show results [SQL Server]

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have this query that shows the execution plan took about 2 seconds but for the results to load (which is one row) took 7 seconds. What would be causing this delay? I see it on the application side as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the actual execution plan with pastetheplan.

Comment: In addition to what Peter said, how many columns is the row? How big are the data types of those columns? Any inordinary / BLOB-like data types storing things like byte arrays, XML, images, etc?

Comment: Presumably some delay either pre execution (plan compilation or RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE wait) or post execution (async_network_io) - the XML for the actual execution plan will have some clues